# Industry playing field

Tags: expressions

Is there a better way to say that something we did " transported us into the industry playing field."

Comment: Almost certainly. What is that expression supposed to mean?

Comment: I think you are confusing two very similar sports metaphors. Both express being or becoming part of some figurative or literal game, but *to be **in** play* or *come **into** play* is most often used with non-personal entities: a ball or an idea or a factor or an infuence is *in play*, while *to be **on** the playing field* or *come **onto** the playing field* is most often used with persons: a player or a company or an organization is *on the playing field*.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without you telling us what you would consider "better".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase you have used has no conventional meaning at all. I am guessing that you are generalising from the phrase *a level playing field*, or perhaps translating from another language; but in English, the only metaphorical use for *playing field* that I can think of is in the set phrase *a level playing field*.

I guess that you mean something like "brought us into the market" (or "market sector"); or more abstractly "put us on the map". I can't think of a conventional phrase for it which has the idea of a playing field.

Comment: 'Arena' might serve as an alternative: '...transported us into the industry's main arena.' - where all the important action happens.

Comment: I think OP is confusing idioms with *in/into* and *on/onto*; *on/onto the (playing) field* is a common metaphor for being/becoming a "player".

Answer (score 0):

In business jargon, "playing field" is the figurative expression for the environment for doing commerce.  Here's a description from Chapter 2, "What business are you in" of [*Goal: The Ball Doesn't Go In By Chance*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VfgbrfO13MsC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=industry%20%22playing%20field%22%20-level%20-even%20-levels%20-leveling%20-skewed%20-uneven%20-equal&source=bl&ots=t0BRfXv6lE&sig=yI2-xf5x0EF_k5os4p3soEn3cbo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBmoVChMI_e-i_a3vxwIVSlQ-Ch0mJAK4#v=onepage&q=industry%20%22playing%20field%22%20-level%20-even%20-levels%20-leveling%20-skewed%20-uneven%20-equal&f=false) by Ferran Soriano.

> Companies talk about the **playing field** to symbolize the markets of
>   industries where they compete to win or lose.  The characteristics of
>   the industry, this symbolic paying filed, are : the size of the
>   market, the demand, the products available and their alternatives,
>   current and potential competitors, the profitability generally
>   obtained, etc.

This year, a federal court in Australia changed the rules about the handling of civil penalties against businesses, and an insurance-industry blogger, Belinda Randall, chose the following headline for a [blog entry](http://www.insuranceflashlight.com/2015/05/05/federal-court-changes-the-playing-field-on-agreed-civil-penalties-in-regulatory-proceedings/):

> Federal Court Changes the **Playing Field** on ‘Agreed’ Civil Penalties in
>   Regulatory Proceedings

According to the google results, the term is most often use with adjectives like "uneven," "unequal," "tilted," and so on to indicate a business environment in which some competitors have an unfair advantage.